# The number occurrence of a character is to be counted in a given line string. Can anyone point out where the error is? The code compiles correctly

Tags: java, recursion, count

The idea is to count the number of occurrence of a given character that a user inputs in a line of string that also is imputed by the user. The idea is to use recursion in Java rather than some sort of loop. The code compiles correctly and runs correctly. But the result does not give a correct answer (does not count the asked character correctly in a given line of string.) Can anyone point out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numberOfLetters {

    public static int letterCounter(String line, String x) 
    {
        if(line.isEmpty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(line.charAt(0) == 'x')
            {
                return 1 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
            }
            else 
            {
                return 0 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      

        System.out.println("Enter a line of a string >_ ");
        String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the character to count >_ ");
        String charac = keyboard.nextLine();        

        int count = letterCounter(inputLine, charac);

        System.out.println("The number of '"+ charac + "' in the input '"+ inputLine + "' is "+ count);
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is tail-recursion, but you have the tag 'tail-recursion', removed tag for you

Comment: It's nothing big, but `0 + ` is not necessary here :). `return letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);` is enough for the `else` branch.

Answer (score 3):

You're testing for 'x' instead of the variable:

```
if(line.charAt(0) == 'x')
```

you need:

```
if(line.charAt(0) == x)
```

Also pass x in as a char instead of String.

Answer (score 1):

1. You say you want to count the number of occurrences of characters, but your "x" parameter is a string. I'd recommend you use "char" to fit with your purpose. If you want "x" to be a string indeed, then your algorithm would need to be somewhat more elaborated and deal with substrings of varying size.

Another issue, you are checking in your "if" statement against the constant 'x', not your parameter.

2. proposed code (don't have Java on this machine, so untested):

   ```
   public static int letterCounter(String line, char x) 
   {
       if(line.isEmpty())
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else 
       {
           if(line.charAt(0) == x)
           {
               return 1 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
           }
           else 
           {
               return 0 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You need **8** whitespaces (not **4** like normal) to use the code formatting if you're using a numeration :). Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check character against character `x`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterCounter {

  public static int letterCounter(String line, char x) 
  {
    if (line.isEmpty()) return 0;

    if(line.charAt(0) == x) {
       return 1 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
    }
    else {
       return 0 + letterCounter(line.substring(1), x);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      

    System.out.println("Enter a line of a string >_ ");
    String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the character to count >_ ");
    String charac = keyboard.nextLine();
    char c =  charac.charAt(0);
    int count = letterCounter(inputLine, c);

    System.out.println("The number of '"+ c + "' in the input '"+ inputLine + "' is "+ count);
    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please notice two code changes - passing character and testing against `x` variable

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution:

```
//Input validation should be performed in main
//Invoke from main
int count = letterCounter(inputLine, charac.charAt(0));

public static int letterCounter(String line, char x) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (char c : line.toCharArray())
        if (c == x)
            counter++;

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to use recursion for this exercise.

Comment: Can't think...how recursion fits for this ex.